# Correlation between weight to loose, target number of days and steps to walk each day

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat, walking, burn-fat

The following specs describe my physique:

- Age: 23 Years
- Weight: 75 kgs
- Height: 5'9''

I'm a typical Indian IT professional with average diet. The only time I could spare to keep myself fit is at night. And the only activity I can do is walking.

I used [this calculator](http://www.calculator.net/ideal-weight-calculator.html?ctype=metric&cage=23&csex=m&cheightfeet=5&cheightinch=10&cheightmeter=175.26&printit=0&x=59&y=13#) to get the recommended weight for my physique and it came out to be about 68 kgs.

Now I'm looking for a correlation between the `weight` I want to loose, the `number of days` in which I want to lose it, and the total `number of steps` I need to walk each day to lose the targeted weight.

I searched a lot but could not get a satisfactory answer. I've also seen numerous posts explaining how 10,000 steps per day can help me lose weight. But I walk more than that in a day. And the weight loss it very slow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many key components missing from that equation like: Calorie Input, Macronutrient breakdown, Energy used to make a step, Metabolic rate (which Is NOT static) and so much more. Also consider using the second calculator on this page to get your "ideal weight" http://strengtheory.com/objective-strength-standards/

Answer (score 3):

Your request is overly simplistic.  That’s why you haven’t been able to find any reliable information.  It’s difficult to develop the correlation you want because each of us is an **individual** capable of losing weight at our own individual pace.  Having said that, it is still possible to lose the weight.  You’ll need to set a realistic goal, and, expend more calories than you consume.  That may mean adding more walking, or, bodyweight exercises to your regime.  Additionally, I would suggest you write down the foods you are consuming to get a better idea of what your caloric intake is.  It’s hard to know how much calories to cut if you don’t know what you are consuming.  Start by keeping a nutrition diary.

Some things just don't fit into a nice neat formula.

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to sound rude but what you're asking leads me to believe that you haven't really done any research into this. Walking a certain EXACT amount of steps won't help with realistically anything, other than ...well counting your steps. If your goal is to lose weight, the NUMBER ONE thing you need to focus on is your diet. Given that your diet is proper, you will lose weight regardless of what activity you're doing. I can link you to a bunch of articles about this, but I think you should research some of this on your own. Nonetheless, I'll give you some tips on how to achieve what you want.

First of all, forget about this correlation business. Weight loss, nutrition, etc are NOT linear processes, and vary on the individual greatly.

My best advice if you want to lose weight, would be to follow an established diet like a low-carb high fat (since you're only walking, you don't really need carbs for any intense exercise, other than fibre of course). A good baseline, would be to take your bodyweight in lbs and multiple this by 14. That's more or less the amount of calories you need to maintain the weight you're at right now. So depending on over how long you want to lose this weight, for example, if you want to lose about 0.5 lbs a week, subtract 500-600 calories from this number and achieve to consume that amount every single day. So if you weigh 165lbs, then you would need approximately 1700-1800 calories a day to lose half a lbs each week (note again this will not exactly be linear).

Of these calories, since you'll want to maintain muscle, make sure you get at least a gram of protein per lbs of bodyweight, i.e 165g since more muscle equates to higher metabolic rate. Around 20-30% of your calories should come from fat, and the rest from low glycemic carbohydrates, focusing on fibre.

Comment: I'd be careful recommending a specific diet when you know nothing about the OP.  Your response makes it seem like "low-carb high fat" is the recommended way to lose weight.  While that may work for you, it may not for others.

Comment: Yes I agree, hence why I said "to follow an established diet like ... ". I don't agree however, that it may not work for others. If properly followed, the research on this diet is well established.